# Can I make Java compiler emit a specific error message and stop compilation?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In C, C++ and C# there's `#error` directive which makes the compiler stop compilation and emit a specified error message.

```
#error "Ouch!"
```

causes VC++9 to emit the following:

```
1>Source.cpp(10) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "Ouch!"
```

and stop compilation.

I can't find anything equivalent for Java.

Does Java have anything like `#error` directive that makes the compiler stop compilation and emit a specific error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, why would you need that in Java? In C/C++ you have `#ifdef` so you can emit an `#error` if a specific static condition is true. In Java, you have no such thing, all code is always compiled. Thus, you will always get the error. Having a file that always yields a compile error is not much use.

*If you really need a file that always raises an error:*

You can simply add a usual syntax error; you will not get a customizable error message but you will get a file that does not compile. You can add a comment behind the error. As most compilers display the line where an error is encountered, that comment will be displayed. Why not simply reuse `#error`:

In your java program:

```
#error // Description
```

Since `#` is not recognized by the Java compiler, this will yield a syntax error.

Comment: I am working on a code-generator and want to show (the valid parts of) the resulting code even if the source document has errors. Since the generator runs in JavaScript, the error messages are hidden in the browsers JavaScript console. This could mislead people to believe that the resulting code was fine - copy it to a file, compile it and use it. If I could put something like #error in there, it would prevent such a case.

I think that is a valid reason to have #error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate you could use "javax annotation processing APIs" to achieve something similar. [see this](http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse/)

The idea is to use:

```
javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING
```

or

```
javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR
```